# Problem Unblocking Assemblies in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-phone-7

I am getting the following error trying to load a basic project template:

`Error  12  Could not load the assembly file://\\psf\home\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsPhonePivotApplication1\WindowsPhonePivotApplication1\obj\Debug\WindowsPhonePivotApplication1.dll. This assembly may have been downloaded from the Web.  If an assembly has been downloaded from the Web, it is flagged by Windows as being a Web file, even if it resides on the local computer. This may prevent it from being used in your project. You can change this designation by changing the file properties. Only unblock assemblies that you trust. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=179545 for more information.   WindowsPhonePivotApplication1`

I don't have the Security tab when I try and modify the DLL to unblock the assembly. Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try copying this assembly locally? Currently it seems to be loaded from a network share. You will need to trust that network location if you want to work this way.

Drive:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\caspol.exe -m -ag 1 -url "file:////\computername\sharename*" FullTrust -exclusive on

Check this KB for details... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320268/

Comment: My entire OS and development tools are running in a Parallels VM. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Not sure Sheehan. But for the time being, to isolate the issue... you should try copying the file locally instead of referring it through a \\ share path. Caspol always creates issues with that. You can also try, caspol -s off from the appropriate framework folder and restart so that code access security doesn't bother you at all [this approach is not recommended though].

Comment: Rahul may be onto something here with network file access. I'm not deep into how this stuff works, but it's ringing a bell. Recommend exploring further.

Comment: Problem exists even if files are local. I can't find the VS Cmd Prompt, I have VS2010 Express.

Comment: Rahul, how would I check the above policy is applied and how would I remove the policy if I added the wrong path?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this very same problem - trying to compile a Silverlight application inside Parallels Desktop 8 virtual machine on a Mac - where the SL output directory was located on the emulated drive (appears in Windows as a network drive).

Very simple fix. You can open up devenv.exe.config located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` and add this line inside the `<Runtime>` node:

`<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>`

e.g.

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="msbuildToolsets" type="Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.ToolsetConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Build.Engine, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </configSections>
    ...
    <runtime>
        <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
        ...
```

To edit the devenv.exe.config file you will also need to open NotePad as administrator. After doing the above I can compile my SL application inside Parallels Virtual Machine, but the above also applies to Silverlight applications hosted on a network drive.

Comment: EDIT: I eventually gave up on hosting code on the shared drive inside parallels - because of file changed notifications not working and Intellisense not rebuilding. Instead I keep an SVN copy of code on my C:\ drive inside the Windows Virtual machine and all other files on the shared drive

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this. These were the steps I took:

1. Downloaded a file, `WP7PiChartsFromDBSOUP.dll`, to my downloads folder (everything locally).
2. Copied this file to `c:/Program Files/` referenced it and attempted to build.
3. Got this error message.
4. Removed the reference, and followed the steps to unblock.
5. Referenced and attempted to build: still same error.
6. Went back to `c:/Program files` and noted that the file was still blocked. Somehow my attempt to block didn't take. So I tried to unblock, closed the properties dialog, then reopened. Somehow my attempt to unblock didn't appear to be working.
7. Went to the downloads folder and unblocked the file that was downloaded to this location, tried to unblock, and it seemed to work. So I felt like I was out of the woods. I copied this file over the file in `c:/Program Files` and reference it in VS2010, closing and reopening VS2010.
8. Same error message. I rebooted the machine and tried again. Same error message. And I know this is gonna sound crazy, but I renamed the dll from that long name to `PieChart.dll`.

And it finally worked.

So, either there was a problem with the name, or maybe changing the name somehow caused the change in blocked status to kick in.

Comment: I had similar issue and only renaming the dll helped. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem trying to build an application on parallels.

I just copied the whole project in a folder under c:/ and works

it seems that parallels shares certain folders (i.e. desktop, documents) between the OS running on the vm and your mac user home folder. because of that windows treats these folders as network shared folder and forbids you to access them.

Comment: Thanks - Couldn't unblock in \program files(x86) but moving to C:\temp, unblocking, and moving back finally 'stuck' as unblocked.

Answer (score 1):

It's on the General tab in file properties from explorer. Either via the DLL in question, or you can do it on the zip file before you extract if it was a download, there will be an unblock button at the bottom right.

Make sure it's from a trusted source.

Comment: See the picture attached. No Unlock button in the bottom right. I didn't download any files. Just tried to create a new project from the standard VS2010 template.

Comment: That picture is for a different file to what is displayed in the error message. Picture=panorama, error=pivot.

Comment: I noticed that also. The same occurs when I do it for pivot, or any file for that matter. Makes me wonder if I need to upgrade to Pro?

Comment: Your problem may stem back to the original download the installed VS. Try uninstalling, then unblock whatever link you are executing to do the install and rerun the install after your sure that has been done. You dont need Pro to make phone projects, express works for many people.

Comment: I am running VS2010 and Win7 Home Premium from a VM. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't have any option to Unblock any file.

Comment: What is the file you executed to install VS? What do you see in file props for this one?

Comment: If accessing files via a share through a VM, this could very well be the source of your problem. Do you have any means of having VS access the files NOT via a network share? ie accessing files on a local driver like c:?

Answer (score 1):

If you still didn't get your answer, I just found the solution. You are saving the application into the network hardrive. So while creating the application, change the location to something like your local disk e.g.,

`C:/Projects`

Then you will be able to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many solutions also with coping file to external usb drive with FAT32 file format, and some other ideas. But finally I've found post by **caliban** here: [Topic about this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a). He links to a program called Streams which helped solving this problem :)

**caliban**:

> Run this line in the command line
>
> streams -s -d directory

[download Streams exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add to the project a text file named `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` having the following contents:

   ```
   <configuration>
       <runtime>
           <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
       </runtime>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. Re-build the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem over VMWare using a mac to load windows 7, if you see the path it starts like a network path, that's why VS gives out about the security.

Take the entire folder project and put it in a physical path starting with C://program files... , then open and compile, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the dll and select properties.  You should see a button to unblock the assembly.

Comment: From the question: `I don't have the Security tab when I try and modify the DLL to unblock the assembly.`